# Conditions for a left Kan extension to be fully faithful?

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:C\rightarrow D$ and $G:C\rightarrow E$ be functors and consider $Lan_{G}F:E\rightarrow D$ . Are there reasonable conditions that we can impose on $F$ and $G$ to ensure that the left Kan extension is fully faithful?